# With a valid schegen visa (French),, Can I apply for tier-4 UK visa, from any of the application center in schegen country?

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa, schengen

While applying for UK visa, It is required to choose the application center. But there isnt much about for Long term tier-4 visa, from where can we apply for UK visa and where we cant.

With a valid Schengen visa (French), Can I apply for tier-4 UK visa from any of the application centers in Schengen country?

Comment: What type of Schengen visa do you hold?

Comment: I have a student visa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Policy on locations from where applications may be submitted is set out in the UK Immigration Rules Part1 (Entry Clearance, section 28) https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-1-leave-to-enter-or-stay-in-the-uk

- An applicant for an entry clearance must be outside the United Kingdom and Islands at the time of the application.
- An application for an entry clearance as a visitor or as a short-term student must be made to any post designated by the Secretary of State to accept such applications.
- Any other application must be made to a post in the country or territory where the applicant is living which has been designated by the Secretary of State to accept applications for entry clearance for that purpose and from that category of applicant. Where there is no such post the applicant must apply to the appropriate designated post outside the country or territory where he is living.

Comment: And for the clause "where there is no such post", we need to travel to other coutry? but we dont need visa for travelling to other schegen countries, so does it permits us to apply fo there?

Comment: @A.B In your question and a subsequent comment you’ve said you have a French student visa. You can’t apply through ‘any’ Schengen country. There is a designated post in France so you must apply from France. If you were living somewhere where there is no post, you’d have to apply through the designated post for that location (eg for Andorra, the designated post is Spain). https://www.gov.uk/find-a-visa-application-centre

Comment: Okay, thank you for the answer :)